# How can i highlight words within tags using Python & regex?

Tags: python, html-parsing

Example text:
`<p><br> i am good </br> hello </p>`

I want to highlight "i am good" and "hello" but not the HTML tags. How can I do it in python? what is the best way to do it? Words may appear between any tag.

Comment: What do you mean by *highlight*?

Comment: Using css is the right way to highlight a html text!

Comment: Also, you [shouldn't ideally be using regex to parse html](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2689986).